Need Help: Accidentally Sent ETH to Wrong Network (Arbitrum Safe)
I’m reaching out with a heavy heart and a hope for some guidance. I’m only 16 and still new to the world of cryptocurrency. Earlier this year, I faced a challenging setback when my crypto wallet was drained. In an effort to safeguard my future investments, I decided to use safer storage solutions and created two safes: one on Ethereum and another on Arbitrum.
However, today I made a mistake due to my lack of technical knowledge. I accidentally sent my ETH from the Ethereum mainnet to my Arbitrum safe. This has left me feeling quite lost and unsure about what to do next. If anyone could offer some advice or point me in the direction of someone who can assist, I would deeply appreciate it. Your help could make a big difference to someone just starting out.
Thank you so much for taking the time to read this. Any help or advice would be immensely valuable.

I understand this must be a stressful situation, fortunately you should be able to recover your funds. Since Artbitrum is EVM-based, you will be able to deploy a Safe on Ethereum with the address of your Safe on Arbitrum, and hence recover your funds.
Can you please read this guide and watch this video? I can only advise you to follow every step carefully.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis
